# What happens when a colossal-sized creature casts Righteous Might?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, creature-size

[Righteous Might](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/righteousMight.htm) doubles the caster's size and provides a number of other benefits. My question is this:

If the caster is already colossal, does it still get the doubled size and other benefits, or does the spell fail because there is no size *category* larger than colossal?

Answer (score 10):

The *Epic Level Handbook* includes dragons that are larger than Colossal, having the size "Colossal+".

The rules for dragons of such size as described as follows:

> Although there is no size category larger than Colossal, the oldest epic dragons deal more damage with their attacks than other Colossal dragons, as shown on the Epic Dragon Face and Reach and Epic Dragon Attacks tables below. In addition, the breath weapon of the oldest epic dragons is a larger cone than most Colossal dragons possess. The size modifier for these dragons remains -8.

The size modifier, space, and reach of a Colossal+ creature remain the same as for a Colossal creature, but their damage rolls go up by one step, as seen in the table at the top [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/dragonEpic.htm).

Comment: The obvious follow-up question is then: what happens when a "Colossal+" caster casts Righteous Might?

Comment: @Grollo Collosal++

Comment: Since no additional size modifiers are given above that, the effects of the spell would still take place, except for the content about size modifier. Simply use the last applicable stats from the largest size category.

Comment: I like your answer, but the epic dragon thing looks like its intention is to simply provide more power to old epic dragons. It does not make any mention of it applying to anything else, so I'm hesitant to mark your answer as "correct" -- I do appreciate the information, though